# Magento 1.9.0.1 download issues

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to download version magento 1.9.0.1 on windows 8, but it wont unzip, it displays a message like  "windows cannot open the folder". the compressed (zipped) folder 'C:\Users\personal\downloads\magento-1.9.0.1.zip' is invalid". on the Magento website the filesize is 32.72 MB whereas when the download apparently is 'done' the zipped file at hand is only 4985kb (4.86 Mb).

I would really appreciate if somebody would help me with this, thanks

Comment: i think the issue with your internet.it is not downloading

Comment: thanks pradeep but can you be a bit more specific if you dont mind and what should i do because i havent had any issues as far as opening websites is concerned, so i wonder what could it be with the internet, thank you

Answer (score 4):

There's dozens of places to download Magento from if you are struggling to get it from the official sources.

Eg. We have a full repo on GitHub, https://github.com/sonassi/magento-ce/tree/1.9.0.1

You can download a zip directly here, https://github.com/sonassi/magento-ce/archive/1.9.0.1.zip

And the sample data here, https://github.com/sonassi/magento-sample-data/tree/1.9.0.0-lite

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, will surely try and see, thanks

Comment: Hi! MageStackDayNeedsYou, do you also have the link for the sample data(for magento 1.9.0.1) as well ? i would really appreciate if you can put the link on here, thanks

Answer (score 0):

check github repo from OpenMage – https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/releases. It contain releases starting from 1.1.1 up to 1.9.4.5.

Security patches can be found in Magento patches mirror repository – https://github.com/akai-z/magento1-open-source-patches

Comment: @Marius why you edit my answer?

Comment: I edited your answer to remove the link to a certain website. A lot of your posts are linking to the same website. Please don't do that anymore because it's spammy.

Comment: it is answer-related. if you check it - all info is on topic. am I wrong?

Comment: answer related does not justify spamming the website with links to your own website. Please stop doing this. If you want to give an answer, answer it fully in here. Not all your posts require a link to your website.